# React function not returning value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to convert a piece of HTML into an image using the package [HTML to Image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-image)

```js
getHTML(id) {
    htmlToImage.toJpeg(document.getElementById(id))
        .then(function (dataURL) {
            console.log(dataURL)
            return dataURL
        });
}
```

**The problem**
When I try `console.log(dataURL)` from within the getHTML function it runs fine but when i try `console.log(this.getHTML('cardFront'))` it returns undefined

Comment: `getHTML` doesn't have a `return` statement so it will always return `undefined`

Comment: `getHTML` doesn't returns anything, so what do you expect to log?